# Prevent iframes and images from loading with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, iframe, loading

i am currently working on a social networking website ,on front page it has a jquery [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) with following options

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
       autoHeight: false,
       animate:"fast",
       active: false,
       collapsible: true });
```

,each section of accordion has either a iframe[iframe or object or embed] containing video from different sources like youtube,vimeo,dailymotion,bliptv,scribd(doc) etc or images from flickr ,imgur etc  wrapped in

```
<div class="embed-container"></div>
```

within .ui-accordion-content

On page load all these iframe and images starts loading and make page really slow
what i want is

1) Stop content of embed-container div from loading completely on page load

2) when a particular accordion section opens ,then embed-container div of that section should load

3)  when accordion section closed ,embed-container div iframe or images should cease all loading

so far i have tried this

```
$('.embed-container').hide();

$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
ui.newContent.find('.embed-container').show();
ui.oldContent.find('.embed-container').hide();
});
```

Looking for a Crossbrowser solution(ie7+,ff3+,chrome)
Thanks

Comment: digg is doing it nicely here http://digg.com/news/all/videos/recent can somebody tell how?

Answer (score 0):

you can load the content of the accordion dynamically so that during the initial load, they contain nothing. then you can assign a "fold id" per fold to indicate what fold was clicked, and load via AJAX the appropriate content. that way, only what we want to see is loaded, and not all.

```
<h3>
    <a href="#3">Section 3</a> //this example uses href as an id
</h3>
<div>
    <p>
        accordion contents
```

then in pseudocode, we get the contents dynamically using AJAX:

```
$.get('url_of_resources?itemid='+itemHref,function(data){
    $('div_of_accordion').html(data);
});
```

Comment: i had this idea but i am avoiding it bacause of lot of ajax requests,thanks

Comment: which would be more of *"a lot"*? the multiple loading of stuff all at onc whether needed or not?, or loading them with AJAX only when needed?

Answer (score 0):

you could just set the iframe's "src" attribute to youtube,vimeo,etc. only after the user clicks on the accordion section.

eg.

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
   ui.newContent.find('.embed-container iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.vimeo.com');
});
```

Comment: Yeah,removing .embed-container content on section closed and injecting it on section open will be my last option,But wants to do it like here http://digg.com/news/all/videos/recent ,dont know how Thanks

Comment: why would it be your last option? It sounds like that's exactly what you wanted. It looks like Digg has a flash video player (ooyala)pre-embeded rather than using an iframe. The flash only gets rendered when the player element is shown. it also has data passed to it to link to the actual source of the video.

Comment: i was expecting more graceful method for "Lazy Loading" of html in jquery ,when i look at that digg link ,they r just doing with display:none over embed-container but they have object tag inside ,not iframe ,may be thats making difference ?

Comment: Yes. The flash player doesn't render until it is shown. But iframes act differently. In Chrome, they still load even though the style is set to "display:none". That's why you should just dynamically set the "src" when a user expands the accordion.